Doubts about getTransactionCount, not working as intended
I am very new to this.
I am trying to make a simple program for self learning that does this:

use slotSubscribe to get root slot number,
use getTransactionCount to get the number of finalized transactions per root slot using minContextSlot param

But
getTransactionCount does not return ascending numbers, but also no. tx that are smaller than the previous one.

Q. What is it returning when 1)I input minContextSlot 2) Without any param 3) With commitment as finalized?
Q. What exactly is minContextSlot?
Q. this API should return the number of transaction till a point in the ledger right? running it consecutively should return bigger and bigger number since the tx are happening ever slot, every epoch?

My algo is that I get tx count till lets say slot10, then till slot11, then slot11-slot10 will give me the number of tx of slot10.
Is this correct? I am sure I am missing something somwhere.
Thanks

The minContextSlot parameter at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransactioncount states:

The minimum slot that the request can be evaluated at

This just means that the RPC has at least caught up to that slot.
The commitment gives the information as of that commitment, so sending finalized will query the newest finalized block for the total number of transactions processed. If you use confirmed, it will query the latest confirmed block instead.
If you're seeing it decrease at any time, it means that you might be hitting a backend with different RPC nodes, and using a minContextSlot that's too old, so a node that's behind is reporting a lower transaction count.
